# convert html data into csv get invalid if data include some of the special character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, export-to-csv

I made a function that converts JSON data into CSV which again the user can download. JSON data is coming from the backend. Recently I noted that if data includes any special character like '#' whole CSV data gets corrupt. what will be the solution to this problem?

Code to convert data into CSV data

```
export const downloadCSV=(data, filename,image)=>
{
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = null;

    if(image !== null && image === true)
    {
        dataType=null
       

    }
    else{
        dataType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';

    }
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', data], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file

        if(image)
        {
            downloadLink.href = data;
        }
        else{
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + data;

        }
        
        
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like the code you've shared has nothing to do with the conversion.

Comment: Probably need to base64 encode it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs You can turn the plaintext to base64 with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob